# Redraw Texture Based Off Disfigured Mesh

Tags: mesh, texturing, objects

I have a full mesh and texture of a dragon in blender, which both work fine.
I have to cut the dragon up into ~20 parts for what I need to do. I cut everything up correctly, but I can't figure out how to get a new texture based on the new object.

As you can see in the image, a small part of the texture is being used.
[image: object and UV mapped texture]

When the mesh is exported alone, it needs the same texture, but redrawn/created to fit.
[image: object and incorrectly UV mapped texture]

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a **bake process** to do that.

Let's say we start with this dragon (anyway, it does not know at all it is not) :

[image]

And you for instance want to separate the horns from the head :

[image]

You here want to remap these UVs like that which does not match the initial texture :

[image]

- Create a new material and a new texture for the head
- Go to node editor and add a texture node to it (with the corresponding texture). **Keep this node selected as below** (this selected node indicates to Cycles where to bake to) :

[image]

- Do the same for the horns part (new material, new texture and same node setup)
- As we will bake and bake uses environment light, set it to full white (RGB = 1, 1, 1) and a strength of 1 : this will keep the same colors as the original

[image]

- We begin with a bake for the head
- Set the new head at the exact same place as the original
- Select the original <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Then select both the new head <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Go to the bake section in the render panel
- Click 'selected to active'
- Adjust a little bit the 'ray distance' in order to avoid artefacts (this may be tuned depending of your mesh)
- And click 'bake'

[image]

- Do the same for the horns :

[image]

Instead of doing that piece by piece, you can also rejoin all your meshes once you have recreated each UV map and each material (eventually remove doubles after the join) and bake them all in one time.

Answer (score 0):

(Warning: The process "to pull off this stunt" is not an easy task to begin with.)

The best shot on this would be using the same method that is used to bake textures from high poly to low poly models. Most tutorials about that focus on baking normal and ao maps but the same method can also be used for diffuse maps.

- It's necessary to have both the original and your cut-up model in one file.
- The original model should be textured correctly
- having the pieces of your cut-up model as one joined object with submeshes instead of several objects makes things easier.
- Watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wHmw783xreY
- Use the original as "high poly" and your cut-up model as "low poly" model

I hope this points you into the right direction.